# Localization doesn't kick in, in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I followed [this guide](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx%20this%20guide) which I was [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265037/asp-net-mvc-3-localization%20recommended), but I can't get it to work at all. When I refer to my string resources, I'm not seing a visual change when I navigate to the page with my browser.

I have only Danish as my viewing language, and I checked to see that the Accept-Languages header does indeed contain da-DK. My resource's name is DashboardMenu.da-DK.resx.

**Edit 1**
I am modifying the UI culture and the normal culture in the following way, in my system.web section of my web.config file:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

The way I am using my resources is the following way (resource files under a directory in my View folder for that the given controller):

[image]

I am then using the resources in the following way (showing you DashboardOverview.cshtml in the Teacher view folder.

[image]

**Edit 2** It should be noted that I am using IIS Express 7.5.

Comment: which approach are you following?

Comment: Sorry, that's important. I just edited the post.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your implementation? How did you switch between languages? Did you change the UI culture info object? etc.

Comment: I modified the question with a ton of details.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly set the danish culture? And can you debug the CurrentCulture value?

Comment: How would I debug the CurrentCulture variable? Changing the cultures explicitly to "da-DK" works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. Turned out that my files should be named ".da.resx" instead of ".da-DK.resx".